# solidity cannot verify ethers.js signed data

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, ecrecover

I have a simple contract which recover the signature signer

signing:

```
const signer = new Wallet(process.env.PRIVATE_KEY)
console.log(signer.address)
const encoded = abiCoder.encode([ "uint" ], [ 1234 ]);
console.log(encoded)
const signature = await signer.signMessage(arrayify(encoded));
const { r, s, v } = splitSignature(signature)


console.log(v)
console.log(r)
console.log(s)
```

recover signer:

```
function recover(uint256 amount, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) view external returns(address signer){

        bytes32 hash =  keccak256(abi.encodePacked(amount));
        bytes32 signedHash = keccak256(abi.encodePacked("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32",hash));
        signer = ecrecover(signedHash, v, r, s);

}
```

but somehow I cannot recover the actual signer.

Answer (score 2):

You are not signing / verifying the same data on both sides.

On the JavaScript you are signing (Prefix is hidden in `signMessage`):

- `keccak256("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32" || abi.encode(uint(1234)))`

But on the Solidity side you are veryfying for

- `keccak256("\x19Ethereum Signed Message:\n32" || keccak256(abi.encode(uint(1234)))`

Assuming that you want to use the solidity code as a reference since you hardcoded the 32 bytes length, you want to sign a **hashed** encoding of `amount` on the JavaScript side.

To do so, change this line :

```
const encoded = abiCoder.encode([ "uint" ], [ 1234 ]);
```

For :

```
const encoded = ethers.utils.keccak256(abiCoder.encode(["uint"], [1234]));
```

And the recovered address matches the signer's address.